# Need a way to get to get the pattern in a string matched with List.stream().anyMatch()

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm matching a list of strings against a list of keywords. The goal is to get a string only one time if it has any of the keywords in it.

Actually I'm doing it with this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i++) {
   if (text.toLowerCase().contains(keywords.get(i))) {
      System.out.println("keyword >>> " + keywords.get(i)
         + " text >>> " + text);
      break;
   }
}
```

I like to know if there is a way to get the keyword if I'm using the java stream API like so:

```
if (keywords.stream().anyMatch(text.toLowerCase()::contains)) {
   System.out.println("keyword >>> " + "how to get the keyword here"
         + " text >>> " + text);
}
```

Comment: Does that not give the result you're after? Not exactly seeing what the problem is.

Comment: @ernest_k I'm building a listview with the results. I want to have the keyword the string matched with in one of the columns. With the stream API I didn't find a way to get the keyword. I want to use the stream API because I think it performs better then the for loop for larger lists.

Comment: The stream API does not perform better than for loops. It's nuanced, but the default conclusion is the opposite. As for your question, don't use `anyMatch`, filter and then use `findAny()` to get the result.

Comment: @omnomnom If you are looking for *exact matches*, then you may want to use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, because it has better lookup performance.

Comment: @MCEmperor how is a HashSet going to be any better than a List when you want to use String.contains()?

Comment: @k314159 Well, I was sleeping when I wrote that comment. I was wired to read `List::contains` instead of `String::contains`.

Comment: @MCEmperor I've noted your edit, which now makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anyMatch` returns a boolean

Using `.filter()` & `findFirst()` you can retrieve a value. Note that if you use `findFirst()` you get an `Optional<String>` and could either use `ifPresent()` like this:

```java
keywords.stream()
    .filter(keyword -> text.toLowerCase().contains(keyword))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(keyWord -> System.out.println("[2] keyword >>> " + keyWord + " text >>> " + text));
```

Or with `Optional.isPresent()` & `Optional.get()`:

```
Optional<String> firstKey = keywords.stream()
    .filter(keyword -> text.toLowerCase().contains(keyword))
    .findFirst();

if (firstKey.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("[2] keyword >>> " + firstKey.get() + " | text >>> " + text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a less fancy alternative to `stream` there is a nicer `for` syntax in Java 1.6+

```
for(String keyword: keywords) {
    if (text.toLowerCase().contains(keyword)) {
        System.out.println("keyword >>> " + keyword
                + "text >>> " + text);
        break;
    }
}
```

I find the `for` syntax easier to read than the `stream` syntax. In a previous job I did a lot of C++ lambda functions with BOOST and the code was hard to parse, and the errors hard to trace.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to print an informational message if the keyword was not found.  This is easily done by moving the `isPresent` test inside the print statement.

```
List<String> keywords =
        Arrays.asList("now", "is", "the", "time");
String text = "what are your names?";
        
Optional<String> opt = keywords.stream()
            .filter(keyword -> text
                    .toLowerCase().contains(keyword))
            .findFirst();


System.out.println(!opt.isPresent() ? "No keyword was found!" : 
                                "keyword >>> " + opt.get() 
                                        + " text >>> " + text);
```

Prints

```
No keyword was found!
```